# how to convert this hard coded values into variables?

Tags: php, sql

I have a small task to do. I want to get the size of a varchar[n] field (to have "n" saved into array). I use a specific and column in my query and it works well but i want to have it from all columns in my db. how can i convert the hard-coded values to variables?

```
$adb->pquery("SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'VTIGER_LEADDETAILS' AND 
column_name='email'",array());

$fieldinfors = $adb->pquery("SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'VTIGER_LEADDETAILS' AND 
column_name='email'", array());
```

Comment: Do you mean how do I process the result of these queries and get the value in `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` into a PHP variable?

Comment: yes, this is what i mean

Comment: The  you had better show us what `pquery()` does as its not vanilla PHP

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anywhere docs for `pquery`, but should works like in other db libraries:

```
$adb->pquery("SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '%s' AND 
column_name='%s'",array('VTIGER_LEADDETAILS', 'email'));
```

and so on. By the way: what are You using to handle db?

Comment: sorry im a noob, why do we put in the array the table name and column name ?

Comment: In most frameworks, variables from this array after sanitization are binded to placeholders (%s) in query. Did it works to You?